# change CAPSLOCK to Ctrl Archlinux command line

Tags: linux, keyboard, key-bindings, tmux

I have Tmux setup on my iMac so that `CAPS` and `Ctrl` are swapped and `C-a` is the prefix. On my old laptop I have archlinux without Xwindows and I can't figure out how to remap those keys. On Mac it was straightforward. How do I do it on my barebones linux setup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a file `ctrl-caps-swap.map`:

```
keymaps 0-127
keycode 29 = Caps_Lock
keycode 58 = Control
```

And load it under root as `loadkeys ./ctrl-caps-swap.map`. You can read more about custom key mappings on [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys_in_console).

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I didn't find that Arch wiki page myself!